# How to install Vuex in fresh Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs3

I need help to someone explain me how to install Vuex in a Nuxt 3 app.

When I install Nuxt 3 using this command `npx nuxi init` I have a fresh Nuxt 3 app, but when I want to use Vuex in Nuxt, I can't because it is not installed by default in a fresh Nuxt 3 app.
So I guess I need to install it using "npm i vuex", okay I understand it's easy, but for me it is not.
I need to someone explain me exactly step by step how to make it working.

There is no documentation on the Internet on how to setup Vuex in a fresh Nuxt 3 app.
If someone can send me a simple project with Nuxt 3 app that is installed by `npx nuxi init` or provide code here, I will learn it why etc...

Answer (score 12):

**First, check Pinia and Nuxt state management.**

[Pinia:](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) Pinia is a store library for Vue, it allows you to share a state across components/pages.

> Pinia is now the new default
>
> The official state management library for Vue has changed to Pinia.
> Pinia has almost the exact same or enhanced API as Vuex 5, described
> in Vuex 5 RFC. You could simply consider Pinia as Vuex 5 with a
> different name. Pinia also works with Vue 2.x as well.
>
> Vuex 3 and 4 will still be maintained. However, it's unlikely to add
> new functionalities to it. Vuex and Pinia can be installed in the same
> project. If you're migrating existing Vuex app to Pinia, it might be a
> suitable option. However, if you're planning to start a new project,
> we highly recommend using Pinia instead.

[Nuxt state management](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management): Nuxt provides useState composable to create a reactive and SSR-friendly shared state across components.

## How to install Vuex in Nuxt3

after the nuxt3 installation you should use this command for installing dependencies :

```
npm i
```

then use this command for installing Vuex:

```
npm install vuex@next --save
```

or

```
yarn add vuex@next --save
```

depend on your package manager.

then go to your root project and create `plugins\` directory.

inside plugins create `vuex.js` file then write these codes inside that:

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
  },
});

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(store);
  // Install the store instance as a plugin
});
```

now in you `app.vue` run these codes to check it :

```html
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$store.state.count);
    },
  };
</script>
```

### summary

1. Install dependencies
2. Install vuex
3. create vuex plugin

Comment: Is it possibile this way to have namespaced stores?

Comment: Ok, I made it myself

Answer (score 4):

I published a module that will work similarly to Nuxt 2, will read all files from `store` folder, supports nesting and SSR.

https://github.com/vedmant/nuxt3-vuex

You can install it by `yarn add nuxt3-vuex-module` or `npm install nuxt3-vuex-module`.

Add to your Nuxt 3 config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    'nuxt3-vuex-module',
  ],
})
```